# Plotly: How to make more space for y axis labels for gantt chart

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am plotting a gantt chart but the Y labels (Task Labels) are not showing:

Below is an example of what am trying to do.

```
data = [
    dict(Task='Morning Sleep', Start='2016-01-01', Finish='2016-01-01 6:00:00', Resource='Sleep'),
    dict(Task='Breakfast', Start='2016-01-01 7:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 7:30:00', Resource='Food'),
    dict(Task='Work', Start='2016-01-01 9:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 11:25:00', Resource='Brain'),
    dict(Task='Break', Start='2016-01-01 11:30:00', Finish='2016-01-01 12:00:00', Resource='Rest'),
    dict(Task='Lunch', Start='2016-01-01 12:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 13:00:00', Resource='Food'),
    dict(Task='Work', Start='2016-01-01 13:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 17:00:00', Resource='Brain'),
    dict(Task='Exercise', Start='2016-01-01 17:30:00', Finish='2016-01-01 18:30:00', Resource='Cardio'), 
    dict(Task='Post Workout Rest', Start='2016-01-01 18:30:00', Finish='2016-01-01 19:00:00', Resource='Rest'),
    dict(Task='Dinner', Start='2016-01-01 19:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 20:00:00', Resource='Food'),
    dict(Task='Evening Sleep', Start='2016-01-01 21:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 23:59:00', Resource='Sleep')
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

colors = dict(Cardio = 'rgb(46, 137, 205)',
              Food = 'rgb(114, 44, 121)',
              Sleep = 'rgb(198, 47, 105)',
              Brain = 'rgb(58, 149, 136)',
              Rest = 'rgb(107, 127, 135)')

fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors=colors, index_col='Resource', title='Daily Schedule',
                      show_colorbar=True, bar_width=0.8, showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True)
py.iplot(fig, filename='gantt-hours-minutes', world_readable=True)
```

It results in the following diagram:

[image: Gantt Chart]

How do make more space on the left side so I can see the whole label?

Comment: How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**

**Option 1:** Specify `fig.update_yaxes(automargin=True)`

**or**

**Option 2:** Adjust left margin `l=200` in `fig.update(margin=go.Layout(l=200))`

---

**The details:**

**Option 1:**

This might be a version issue or only related to `iplot`. I'm using `plotly.graph_objects`, and in order to reproduce your issue I have to actively set `automargin=False`:

**Plot 1.1:** `fig.update_yaxes(automargin=False)`

[image]

**Code 1:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pio.renderers.default = 'jupyterlab'
#pio.renderers.default = 'browser'


data = [
    dict(Task='Morning Sleep', Start='2016-01-01', Finish='2016-01-01 6:00:00', Resource='Sleep'),
    dict(Task='Breakfast', Start='2016-01-01 7:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 7:30:00', Resource='Food'),
    dict(Task='Work', Start='2016-01-01 9:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 11:25:00', Resource='Brain'),
    dict(Task='Break', Start='2016-01-01 11:30:00', Finish='2016-01-01 12:00:00', Resource='Rest'),
    dict(Task='Lunch', Start='2016-01-01 12:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 13:00:00', Resource='Food'),
    dict(Task='Work', Start='2016-01-01 13:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 17:00:00', Resource='Brain'),
    dict(Task='Exercise', Start='2016-01-01 17:30:00', Finish='2016-01-01 18:30:00', Resource='Cardio'), 
    dict(Task='Post Workout Rest', Start='2016-01-01 18:30:00', Finish='2016-01-01 19:00:00', Resource='Rest'),
    dict(Task='Dinner', Start='2016-01-01 19:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 20:00:00', Resource='Food'),
    dict(Task='Evening Sleep', Start='2016-01-01 21:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 23:59:00', Resource='Sleep')
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

colors = dict(Cardio = 'rgb(46, 137, 205)',
              Food = 'rgb(114, 44, 121)',
              Sleep = 'rgb(198, 47, 105)',
              Brain = 'rgb(58, 149, 136)',
              Rest = 'rgb(107, 127, 135)')



fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors=colors, index_col='Resource', title='Daily Schedule',
                      show_colorbar=True, bar_width=0.8, showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True)

fig.update_yaxes(automargin=False)

fig.show()
```

At the time being (I'm on Plotly `'4.2.0'`), setting `automargin=True` or not specifying it at all gives you this:

**PLot 1.2:** `fig.update_yaxes(automargin=True)`

[image]

**Option 2:** `fig.update(margin=go.Layout(l=200))`

**Plot 2.1:**

I've added border to the plot area and color to the bacground to illustrate what is being adjusted.

**Plot 2:**

[image]

**Code 2:**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pio.renderers.default = 'jupyterlab'
#pio.renderers.default = 'browser'


data = [
    dict(Task='Morning Sleep', Start='2016-01-01', Finish='2016-01-01 6:00:00', Resource='Sleep'),
    dict(Task='Breakfast', Start='2016-01-01 7:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 7:30:00', Resource='Food'),
    dict(Task='Work', Start='2016-01-01 9:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 11:25:00', Resource='Brain'),
    dict(Task='Break', Start='2016-01-01 11:30:00', Finish='2016-01-01 12:00:00', Resource='Rest'),
    dict(Task='Lunch', Start='2016-01-01 12:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 13:00:00', Resource='Food'),
    dict(Task='Work', Start='2016-01-01 13:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 17:00:00', Resource='Brain'),
    dict(Task='Exercise', Start='2016-01-01 17:30:00', Finish='2016-01-01 18:30:00', Resource='Cardio'), 
    dict(Task='Post Workout Rest', Start='2016-01-01 18:30:00', Finish='2016-01-01 19:00:00', Resource='Rest'),
    dict(Task='Dinner', Start='2016-01-01 19:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 20:00:00', Resource='Food'),
    dict(Task='Evening Sleep', Start='2016-01-01 21:00:00', Finish='2016-01-01 23:59:00', Resource='Sleep')
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

colors = dict(Cardio = 'rgb(46, 137, 205)',
              Food = 'rgb(114, 44, 121)',
              Sleep = 'rgb(198, 47, 105)',
              Brain = 'rgb(58, 149, 136)',
              Rest = 'rgb(107, 127, 135)')



fig = ff.create_gantt(df, colors=colors, index_col='Resource', title='Daily Schedule',
                      show_colorbar=True, bar_width=0.8, showgrid_x=True, showgrid_y=True)

# add borders
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=1, linecolor='black', mirror=True)

fig.update_yaxes(automargin=False)

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=500,
    height=500,
    margin=go.layout.Margin(
        l=150,
        r=5,
        b=100,
        t=100,
        pad=4
    ),
    paper_bgcolor="LightSteelBlue",
)

fig.show()
```

Now you should be able to get what you want either way.